# Visual Studio looking in my asp.net publish profiles folder for my azure function pubxml file

Tags: visual-studio, azure, msbuild, azure-functions

I got something messed up in the publishing of my azure function. Visual studio is looking for my azure function's publish profile file in another projects folder (my asp.net site). It doesn't seem like this is the way it's supposed to work, shouldn't msbuild look for the publish profile  (.pubxml) in the properties folder under the project I'm trying to publish? Instead it's looking under the properties folder of the asp.net mvc site in the solution.

Does anyone think it has to do with me referencing the asp.net site as a reference in the azure function project?

How do I reset the path where Visual Studio looks for the projects pubxml file?

I've tried resetting VS, deleting the publish profile file and creating a new one and a few other things but every time I try and publish the azure function to azure it fails to publish because it's looking in the incorrect place!

Here is what the first error says in the output window. It shows it's looking for my pubxml file in in another projects folder. the Yogabandy2017 folder, when it should be the PreEventCancellationFunction folder

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4368,5): error : The value for PublishProfile is set to 'Yogabandy2017Functions - Web Deploy', expected to find the file at 'C:\Users\Charles Pareto\Source\Workspaces\YogaBandy2017\YogaBandy2017\YogaBandy2017\Properties\PublishProfiles\Yogabandy2017Functions - Web Deploy.pubxml' but it could not be found. [C:\Users\Charles Pareto\Source\Workspaces\YogaBandy2017\YogaBandy2017\YogaBandy2017\YogaBandy2017.csproj]

Comment: Do you mean the project `YogaBandy2017` is a asp.net mvc site? When you publish your azure function project, VS try to find the .pubxml file in the properties folder under the asp.net mvc site project `YogaBandy2017`? Are you sure you select the project is azure function project not asp.net mvc site when you publish. If not, could you please share us some screenshots or gif/video to check?

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I am running into exactly the same thing

Comment: yes, it's been a while, but I think it was because I hadn't referenced other projects correctly in the function app project.

Comment: How did you _reference the other projects correctly_? I have the same issue and am stuck! Found this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/933) and can only make it work by adding the publish profile to the other folder, but that actually deploys the Web API to the Function.@JohnSmith / Leo did you figure it out?

Comment: Did anyone else solve this issue? I have exactly the same problem. I'm not too keen on the workaround where you put the pubxml into the other project.